# IIS 8 redirect for browsers supporting only TLS 1.0 or lower

Tags: iis, ssl

due to security requirements, I have disabled TLS 1.0 and lower in IIS 8.
To be somewhat friendly to users using old browsers that only support TLS 1.0 or lower, I want to redirect them to a certain page.

I have installed the "MS URL Rewrite 2.0" Module, that I use for http > https redirects anyway, but I can't find the condition or servervariable to get the negotiated TLS version value.

Does anyone know, how to accomplish that, or point me into the right direction?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

No connection will be made if the client and server can't agree on a protocol.  Without a connection between your server and the client, you can't send a redirect to the client.

To accomplish what you're after, you'd need to permit the TLS 1.0 connection to be established, then server side inspect the connection and do a conditional redirect...

```
if AgreedOnProtocol = TLS 1.0 then 
   response.redirect "http://someinsecuredomain.com/whyyourbrowsersucks.html" 
else 
  <do your normal thing>
```

The above is pseudocode (hopefully obviously).

Comment: The following is opinion and adding as a comment so as to not be part of the answer: Now, if you've taken the time to disable the really bad (SSL) connections and put your cipher suites in a good order, what you're trying to do is really above and beyond the call.  You're trying to bend over backwards to help people running... WinXP and IE6.0 I think?  WinXP has been out of support for like a year and a half now.

Comment: I know, and I am willing to reenable TLS 1 for the redirect purpose only. But I am still trying to find out how the do the redirect. I tried to do it with an IIS Module, but I can't find the properties that would indicate the negotiated tls version.

Comment: I started to look into turning the pseudocode above into actual code for you, and wow, what a rabbit hole I ended up going down.  It seems that [IIS doesn't get to see the protocol because all that negotiation happens inside of `https.sys`](http://serverfault.com/questions/637261/is-it-possible-to-configure-iis-to-redirect-based-on-the-ssl-cipher-suite-used-f).  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009018/check-ssl-protocol-cipher-other-properties-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application) has two inventive solutions, one using VM's as load balances and another doing some log probing.

Comment: yes, that is all I could find out, before I asked my question on SO. couldn't believe first that there is no easy solution.