# How to get TLS/SSL related information in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to gain more information of a current TLS/SSL request in an ASP.NET Core MVC Controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {        
        public IActionResult About()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.IsHttps)
            {
                // How to get more information about the transport layer ?

                ViewData["Message"] = "Connection via TLS/SSL - ... missing details ...";
            }

            return View();
        }        
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the properties like used TLS version, cipher and so on ?

I know that this is not possible in ASP.NET MVC as stated in
[Check ssl protocol, cipher & other properties in an asp.net mvc 4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009018/check-ssl-protocol-cipher-other-properties-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application). Perhaps the new framework with Kestrel offers this kind of information I was not able to find so far.

Comment: No, this information is not yet available. You can request it here: https://github.com/aspnet/kestrelhttpserver

Answer (score 4):

You can get those values using the `Features` property from the `HttpContext`. 
If you call:

```
var tlsHandshakeFeature = request.HttpContext.Features.Get<ITlsHandshakeFeature>();
```

[ITlsHandshakeFeature](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Servers/Connections.Abstractions/src/Features/ITlsHandshakeFeature.cs) will give you the TLS version (Protocol property), the CipherAlgorithm, among many other things.
You can also `Get` the [ITlsConnectionFeature](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Features/src/ITlsConnectionFeature.cs) which will give you the certificates.

Comment: Is this documented and actively supported?

Comment: This works for my locally, I can see the TLS version, however when I deploy to an Azure App service I see `None` for the protocol property.  Any thoughts?

Comment: To answer my own comment, for an Azure App Service, microsoft has a terminating load balancer in front of the end server, where they don't pass that meta down. So this feature will not work. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57308558/2270340) should now be valid for .NET 8, as it can be seen in [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/46824). However, if you are using an older version, you can use the following (found in the linked PR itself).

```cs
var sslStream = context.Features.Get<SslStream>();
var sslProtocol = sslStream.SslProtocol;
var cipherSuite = sslStream.NegotiatedCipherSuite;
```