# How to find the tls version is being used when API calling

Tags: c#, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.1

How to find the TLS version when an API call in C# (RestClient and WebRequest)?
How to change the TLS version? Is there any way to change TLS version?

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869135/is-that-possible-to-send-httpwebrequest-using-tls1-2-on-net-4-0-framework).

Comment: I hope this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53485283/3936696